# batch download zipped files in R

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to download zipped files from website like http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/.
Since there are many files, is there a way to download them in batch instead of one by one?  Ideally, the downloaded files can be unzipped in batch after downloading.
I tried to use system(curl http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/QCLCD") etc.. but got many errors and status 127 warnings.

Any idea or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need server side access to put everything in a batch file. Perhaps you could download using one of the parallel frameworks offered in R?

Comment: Can we vote to close this?

Comment: Can you tick mark my answer?

Comment: Yes. I did. I previously couldn't do it because my reputation score wasn't high enough! Thanks again for your brilliant solution!

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
library(XML)
url<-c("http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/")
doc<-htmlParse(url)
#get <a> nodes.
Anodes<-getNodeSet(doc,"//a")
#get the ones with .zip's and .gz's
files<-grep("*.gz|*.zip",sapply(Anodes, function(Anode) xmlGetAttr(Anode,"href")),value=TRUE)
#make the full url
urls<-paste(url,files,sep="")
#Download each file.
mapply(function(x,y) download.file(x,y),urls,files)
```

Comment: This writes to the working directory, which you can set with `setwd()`.  To unzip them, `lapply(grep(".zip",files, value=true),unzip)` will work for the zip files and  `lapply(grep(".tar.gz",files, value=true),untar)` will work for tar.gz files (though you may be able to read.table() the tar.gz files directly.

Comment: Thanks so much mgriebe! This really works very well!

Answer (score 1):

It's not R, but you could easily use the program [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), ignoring robots.txt:

> wget -r --no-parent -e robots=off --accept *.gz 
>   http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it:

```
### Load XML package, for 'htmlParse'
require(XML)

### Read in HTML contents, extract file names.
root <- 'http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/'
doc  <- htmlParse(root)
fnames <- xpathSApply(doc, '//a[@href]', xmlValue)

### Keep only zip files, and create url paths to scrape.
fnames <- grep('zip$', fnames, value = T)
paths  <- paste0(root, fnames)
```

Now that you have a vector of url's and corresponding file-name's in R, you can download them to your hard disk. You have two options. You can download in serial, or in parallel.

```
### Download data in serial, saving to the current working directory.
mapply(download.file, url = paths, destfile = fnames)

### Download data in parallel, also saving to current working directory.
require(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterMap(cl, download.file, url = paths, destfile = fnames, 
           .scheduling = 'dynamic')
```

If you choose to download in parallel, I recommend considering 'dynamic' scheduling, which means that each core won't have to wait for others to finish before starting its next download. The downside to dynamic scheduling is the added communication overhead, but since the process of downloading ~50mb files is not very resource intensive, it will be worth it to use this option so long as files download at slightly varying speeds.

Lastly, if you want to also include `tar` files as well, change the regular expression to

```
fnames <- grep('(zip)|(gz)$', fnames, value = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

To download everything under that directory you can do this:

```
wget -r -e robots=off http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/qclcd_ascii/
```